# How to render a pdf file as pdf in browser using django

Tags: django, python-3.x, pdf

I am using Django web frame work. I am taking pdf files from users (notes/book/etc). Then I want to display those pdf in website, but I could not find a way. Methods that failed 1)iframe 2)simple rendering using django 3)pdf.js library. Also browser blocks rendering initially. Care to suggest a method and steps to implement it.

Comment: I would add full console error messages, and any network traffic errors to your question. Screenshots might also help.

Comment: I would update soon

Comment: Actually the problem is my pdf is being displayed in browser but depending upon browser. For chromium its displaying for firefox its not. I have used embed tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the answer has to be very very clear here. You can not display pdf using. There is no such library for that. Like pdf.js for javascript based frameworks. I have done the research. So if you want a really good pdf viewer for your django powered website you have to use pdf.js for sure. I have asked people working with django professionally.

output in firefox
[image: output in firefox]

ouput in chromium browser
[image: output in chromium browser]

Now 2nd output is what we want
here is the code
[image: django code]

Answer (score 0):

I the answer to your problem is here :

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/outputting-pdf/

Comment: No, @ubisun you misread the question. Link you have given is for rendering html to pdf dynamically using django. I already have a pdf which I want to render. Your suggestion is unrealted actually.